# Clone a marc4j record Class

Tags: java

I am trying to clone a Recrod class from Java marc4j 
with

```
private Record copyRecord(Record record) {
     Record f = new Record();
     f.set(record.get());
     return f;
}
```

However I get a java.lang.RuntimeException: with  error: org.marc4j.marc.Record is abstract; cannot be instantiated
on line 
f.set(record.get());

Please keep in mind that my java skills are limited, 
so the question is

How can I get a clone of the original class that I can manipulate and change its values without messing around with the original class data and methods??

Thanks in advance 
Regards,
Harry

Answer (score 2):

You cannot instantiate `Record` because it is an interface.

If you are wanting to copy the `Record` you can use a `MarcStreamWriter` and a `MarcStreamReader` like so - However this does seem over the top:

```
public Record copyRecord(Record r)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream boas = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    MarcStreamWriter mw = new MarcStreamWriter(boas);
    mw.write(r);

    byte[] ba = boas.toByteArray();
    ByteArrayInputStream bois = new ByteArrayInputStream(ba);
    MarcStreamReader mr = new MarcStreamReader(bois);
    Record r2 = null;
    if(mr.hasNext())
        r2 = mr.next();
    return r2;
}
```

You might have to take care of some exceptions here and also close the writers/readers.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I am going to check it for the future. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `MarcFactory`. Add the `Leader`, the `Errors`, and the `VariableFields`. If I am correct, that should be complete.

```
private static Record cloneRecord(Record inputRecord) {
    Record outputRecord = MarcFactory.newInstance().newRecord();
    outputRecord.setLeader(MarcFactory.newInstance().newLeader(inputRecord.getLeader().marshal()));

    if (inputRecord.hasErrors()) {
        inputRecord.getErrors().forEach(inputError - > {
            outputRecord.getErrors().add(new MarcError(inputError.curField, inputError.curSubfield, inputError.severity, inputError.message));
        });
    }

    for (ControlField inputControlField: inputRecord.getControlFields()) {
        outputRecord.addVariableField(MarcFactory.newInstance().newControlField(inputControlField.getTag(), inputControlField.getData()));
    }

    for (DataField inputDataField: inputRecord.getDataFields()) {
        DataField outputDataField = MarcFactory.newInstance().newDataField(inputDataField.getTag(), inputDataField.getIndicator1(), inputDataField.getIndicator2());
        inputDataField.getSubfields().forEach(inputSubfield - > {
            outputDataField.addSubfield(MarcFactory.newInstance().newSubfield(inputSubfield.getCode(), inputSubfield.getData()));
        });
        outputRecord.addVariableField(outputDataField);
    }

    return outputRecord;
}
```